# How to use Until activity in Azure Data Factory to iterate REST API?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to do an activity in Azure Data Factory. It consists of reading data from an API, and at each reading, I would add +1 in the value of the variable until I reach a certain value, as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

URL:

[image]

However, the variable never goes beyond the value 2, so I get stuck in a loop. Does anyone have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Have you checked out the [pagination support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) to see if it can help with your case?

Comment: Can you try adding another `set variable` variable activity to assign "dyn" variable value to "page_num" variable inside until activity?

Comment: @ray yes, didn't help at all

Comment: @NiharikaMoola-MT i tried that too, but the variable keeps stuck in the value of '2'

Comment: How long does approach take just out of interest?  I would normally use a Copy activity to download APIs and use the pagination.  I was able to call this API and download to a single json file in data lake about 8 mins.  The Web activity approach is fine if you want to do something directly with the results in the pipeline but it is a bit limited.

Comment: @wBob how could i use the pagination with a copy data activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to try to put the `Web Activity` inside the `Until Activity`. As the webservice is open and can be accessed without authentication, I made an example that worked in my environment.

```json
{
    "name": "Get_NBA_Stats",
    "properties": {
        "activities": [
            {
                "name": "Retrieve all NBA results",
                "type": "Until",
                "dependsOn": [
                    {
                        "activity": "Set startpage",
                        "dependencyConditions": [
                            "Succeeded"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "expression": {
                        "value": "@equals(activity('Get page from BallDontLie_io').output.meta.total_pages, activity('Get page from BallDontLie_io').output.meta.current_page)",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "activities": [
                        {
                            "name": "Get page from BallDontLie_io",
                            "type": "WebActivity",
                            "dependsOn": [],
                            "policy": {
                                "timeout": "7.00:00:00",
                                "retry": 0,
                                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                                "secureOutput": false,
                                "secureInput": false
                            },
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "url": {
                                    "value": "@Concat('https://www.balldontlie.io/api/v1/games?per_page=100&page=',variables('page'))",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                },
                                "method": "GET"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Set next page",
                            "type": "SetVariable",
                            "dependsOn": [
                                {
                                    "activity": "Get page from BallDontLie_io",
                                    "dependencyConditions": [
                                        "Succeeded"
                                    ]
                                }
                            ],
                            "userProperties": [],
                            "typeProperties": {
                                "variableName": "page",
                                "value": {
                                    "value": "@string(activity('Get page from BallDontLie_io').output.meta.next_page)",
                                    "type": "Expression"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "timeout": "7.00:00:00"
                }
            },
            {
                "name": "Set startpage",
                "type": "SetVariable",
                "dependsOn": [],
                "userProperties": [],
                "typeProperties": {
                    "variableName": "page",
                    "value": "1"
                }
            }
        ],
        "variables": {
            "page": {
                "type": "String",
                "defaultValue": "1"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "lastPublishTime": "2021-10-25T13:32:04Z"
    },
    "type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

1. Set page to the default ( webservice start pagination at 1 ).
2. Set condition when the loop should stop (`meta.total_pages` equals `meta.current_page`).
3. Retrieve all pages in a loop.
4. Update the page variable with `meta.next_page`

You might want to check the Expression if it stops in time, and does not continue looping and rack up your Azure bill.

Comment: Oh bro, thank you very much!! Just one question, how do i set the total_pages so then the loop can stop?

Comment: It is returned by the response of the website, meta.total_pages. See the condition of the Until loop: @equals(*activity('Get page from BallDontLie_io').output.meta.total_pages*, activity('Get page from BallDontLie_io').output.meta.current_page)

Comment: is there a way  i can use that with a copy data activity?

Answer (score 0):

The trouble with the [Until activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-until-activity) approach and paging Web activity calls is that it runs in **serial**, ie one after the other.  I tried the approach above and it ran over 512 pages (at 100 items per page) for that API in **48 minutes**.

I guess which approach you use depends on what you are doing with the response but I used a Copy activity approach [with pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) which downloads the response as a single JSON file to a data lake which runs in **9 minutes**.  I found I had to raise the `Request interval (ms)` to 1000ms to stop it overwhelming the API but it the pipeline succeeds:

[image: Synapse Pipeline Web call]

Here I use a single call with the Web activity to get the total_pages, but the Copy activity is doing the main work.

```
@string(activity('Web Get Ballgames API').output.meta.total_pages)
```

I also set the Pagination rules to pick the next page automatically:

```
QueryParameters.page:  $.meta.next_page
```

Comment: can you show me the json code of this activity?

Comment: Hi, just add the items I've mentioned above to the Pagination section - `QueryParameters.page`  with value of `$.meta.next_page`.  Make sure you understand [pagination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-rest?tabs=data-factory#pagination-support) first.